# Stop app from launching on AVD start

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm using the android emulator and I want to start an AVD but without my app being fired. Now, when my AVD start my app will start too, automatically.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you launching your AVD when running your app from your IDE?  If so, we'd need to know your IDE - in your run configuration there is usually a setting to select the launch activity, which can be set to "do nothing".

Comment: I tried with my IDE (Eclipse) and with the emulator -avd command. Same results

Answer (score 0):

You are probably "running" the app, not "launching the AVD" - which is why the app launches. Eclipse has the Android Virtual Device manager in the "Window" menu.

You should be able to select and launch your AVD from that menu without it automatically launching any app (including any projects you have) unless you have specifically configured the AVD to do so (somehow).